# MySQL table caching returns stale data

Tags: mysql, caching

I have query caching disabled (it's disabled by default on my installation) but kept getting outdated data in my application. For example, I would do a `SELECT *` on my `review` table, insert a new row and then do another `SELECT *`, but the new review wouldn't show up (although it would be there if I browsed to the table in `phpMyAdmin`). I disabled table caching (`table_cache = 0`) and things started working fine, with all new reviews showing up on the second `SELECT *`.

The MySQL documentation says that

> The query cache does not return stale
>   data. When tables are modified, any
>   relevant entries in the query cache
>   are flushed.

Is this not true for the table cache as well? Is there a way to have MySQL use table caching, but force it to flush the cache once a cached table is modified? I couldn't really find much to go by in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_cache) .

Comment: Are you sure it's really stale data, because data inserted *after* your SELECT executes will obviously not show up in the SELECT resultset but would if the SELECT is re-run after the data has been inserted.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're not having a bug in the code that fetches data ? And areyou sure there's not an uncommited transaction by the time you run your second select ?

Comment: No, not sure at all. But if it's uncommitted when I do the second SELECT, then why does it show up in phpMyAdmin? And then, why does the SELECT->INSERT->SELECT sequence work as one might expect once I disable table caching?

Comment: The latter could be random behavior. Most likely you have some internal caching in your framework if you use one. *table_cache* refers to the number of open tables. It is impossible for the query cache to return stale data, if the table is actually changed.